# When one have a Master's Degree, he's educated to ... level?

Tags: word-choice

For example, if someone has a Bachelor's Degree, we can say that *he's educated to degree level*.

So, when the same guy obtains a Master's Degree, how would you say that same sentence? *He's educated to ... level.*

Comment: is it "post graduate" ..??

Comment: I think this has been dealt with before. Have you checked previous posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Masters level" (or "Master's level") seems to be the common term.  See, for example, [Oxford University Department of Education](http://www.education.ox.ac.uk/courses/pgce/masters-level-accreditation/)

Comment: Not the best University to choose as an example MSc is Masters level but you can get an MA if you are only educated to degree level

Comment: Why is Masters acceptable here? I always thought the possessive form was compulsory when it comes to degrees.

Comment: A quick search on Google UK shows several UK universities that don't add the apostrophe.  Perhaps it's a plural, rather than a possessive, that is that the degree is at the level of other Masters.